# Already sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array including user's inputs. The program is about Bubble sort, Selection sort and Insertion sort. First Bubble, Second Selection and then Insertion sort comes.

I couldn't manage to solve a problem. When the code run into selection sort, the array is already sorted by bubble sort.

I tried to make 2 temporary arrays at first to use the "source array" at selection and insertion sorting but those arrays re-arranged by bubble sort again. ( Which I don't understand why )

Is there any way to sort my array seperately or I have to make them methods ? I'm counting the swaps and comparisons also BTW. Thanks !

```
    System.out.println("• Please enter the number of elements in the Sorting Bag:");
    length = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("• The number of elements: " + length);

    int[] SorBag = new int[length];
    int[] SorBag2 = new int[length];
    int[] SorBag3 = new int[length];

    System.out.println("• Please enter the elements of Sorting Bag:");
    for (int i = 0; i < SorBag.length ; i++) {
        SorBag[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    SorBag2 = SorBag;
    SorBag3 = SorBag;

    System.out.print("• Elements in the Sorting Bag are:");
    for (int j = 0; j < SorBag.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(" " + SorBag[j]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");

    //Bubble Sort    
    for (int i = 1; i < SorBag.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SorBag.length - i; j++) {
            BComparison++;
            if (SorBag[j] > SorBag[j + 1]) {
                BSwaps++;
                temp1 = SorBag[j + 1];
                SorBag[j + 1] = SorBag[j];
                SorBag[j] = temp1;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("• Bubble Sort:");
    for (int k = 0; k < SorBag.length; k++) {
        System.out.print(" " + SorBag[k] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("Comparisons: " + BComparison + " Swaps: " + BSwaps);
    System.out.println(" ");

    //Selection Sort
    for (int i = 0; i < SorBag2.length; i++) {
        min = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < SorBag2.length; j++) {
            SComparison++;

            if (SorBag2[j] < SorBag2[min]) {
                min = j;
            }

            if (min != i) {

                temp2 = SorBag2[i];
                SorBag2[i] = SorBag2[min];
                SorBag2[min] = temp2;
                SSwaps++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.print("• Selection Sort:");
    for (int k = 0; k < SorBag2.length; k++) {
        System.out.print(" " + SorBag2[k] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("Comparisons: " + SComparison + " Swaps: " + SSwaps);
    System.out.println(" ");

    //Insertion Sort
    for (int i = 1; i < SorBag3.length; i++) {

        int j = 0;

        while (j > i && SorBag3[j] < SorBag3[j - 1]) {

            temp3 = SorBag3[j];
            SorBag3[j] = SorBag3[j - 1];
            SorBag3[j - 1] = temp3;

            ISwaps++;

            j--;
        }

        IComparison++;
    }
    System.out.print("• Insertion Sort:");
    for (int k = 0; k < SorBag3.length; k++) {
        System.out.print(" " + SorBag3[k] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("Comparisons: " + IComparison + " Swaps: " + ISwaps);
    System.out.println(" ");

}
}
```

Comment: You are going to add the relevant parts of your code, right?

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: I don't understand how you could hold a source array and still sort that in your loop/method.

Comment: If your array is already sorted by the time you hit the second sort, that means you modified the original user input array and didn't reset it. You can write the sorts in a separate function and pass the array as a parameter

Comment: How can I reset it ?

Comment: Now that you uploaded your code, once can see that since SorBag2 and 3 point to SorBag, they will also be already sorted.

Comment: Yeah which I don't want to be.

Comment: Instead of writing everything in the main method, write separate methods and call them from main(). Also, for Sorbag2 and Sorbag3, write for loops to manually copy the elements of sorbag to 2 and 3, so that the pointers are not pointing to the same place in memory.

Comment: So if I don't want to make them methods, I can use loops to solve this right ?

Comment: If you don't want to make methods, make loops to manually copy each element of sorbag to sorbag2 and sorbag3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SorBag2 = SorBag` and `SorBag3 = SorBag` copies the reference of `SorBag` to the other two arrays, instead of only copying the data. So instead of:

```
System.out.println("• Please enter the elements of Sorting Bag:");
for (int i = 0; i < SorBag.length ; i++) {
    SorBag[i] = input.nextInt();
}

SorBag2 = SorBag;
SorBag3 = SorBag;
```

Try this:

```
System.out.println("• Please enter the elements of Sorting Bag:");
for (int i = 0; i < SorBag.length ; i++) {
    int nextInt = intput.nextInt();
    SorBag[i] = nextInt;
    SorBag2[i] = nextInt;
    SorBag3[i] = nextInt;        
}
```

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question, [please accept it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Also, a recommendation: use `sorBag` instead of `SorBag`. It's not a must, but in most programming languages variables/field-names start with a lower-case.